# Scatter Plot Points lose color when using boost.js for Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been trying to figure out why the colors of each point on a scatter plot disappear when using boost.js module for Highcharts. I need boost.js module because the amount of points I am generating is so great that the web site's performance is greatly diminished without using boost.js.

I made a fiddle to simulate what I am trying to accomplish.

If you comment out the boost.js script reference in the fiddle you will see the colors for each point on the scatter plot the way I am trying to achieve but notice the performance on the website is very poor.

I need the performance that boost.js offers while still maintaining the colors of each scatter plot point.

So my question is, how do you keep the colors for each point while maintaining performance?

**UPDATE:**

**WITHOUT** boost.js https://jsfiddle.net/rtunis/9rLdfzq7/4/

**WITH** boost.js https://jsfiddle.net/rtunis/9rLdfzq7/3/

Javascript:

```
var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 350; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 350; j++) {
        var point = {
            datum: i,
            y: i,
            x: j,
            color: "hsla(" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + ", 100%, 50%, 0.75)"
        };
        data.push(point);
    }
}

// create the chart and store it
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        renderTo: 'map',
        panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'TestTitle'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Subtitle Test'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Longitude'
        },
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,

    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Latitude'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square',
                radius: 1
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    halo: {
                        opacity: 0.75,
                        size: 4,
                        attributes: {
                            zIndex: 4,
                            fill: 'gray',
                            'stroke-width': 1,
                            stroke: 'black'
                        }
                     }
                  }
              },
      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
          pointFormat: '<b>Datum:</b> {point.datum:.2f}<br/><b>Longitude:</b> {point.x:.5f}<br/><b>Latitude:</b> {point.y:.5f}<br/>'
      },
      turboThreshold: 150000
    }
  },
  responsive: {
      rules: [{
          condition: {
              maxWidth: 500,
              minWidth: 500
          }
      }]
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'SeriesName',
      data: data,
  }]
});
```

Comment: I think I solved it for now. Check here for solution. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5999

Comment: Yes, the only way to achieve that is editing the internal function for drawing points. The color is taken from the series without checking each point's color.